# Problem accessing array variable inside rdd operation in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

My input is some csv/tsv or whatever delimiter separated file and its header. I want to map by any column as key and the whole row as value. I ran the below code fine on my machine but failed when tested in yarn-cluster mode.

```java
public class SparkController implements java.io.Serializable {
    String DELIMITER;
    String[] header;
    String path;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // some parse function
        // say input file is a csv likes: (id,timestamp,ip)
        // header = [ "id", "timestamp", "ip" ]
        // DELIMITER = ","
        SparkController sparkController = new SparkController();
        sparkController.parseArgs(args);

        JavaPariRDD<String, String> pairRdd = sparkController.map2PairRdd("ip");

    }

    private JavaPariRDD<String, String> map2PairRdd(String column) {
        JavaRDD<String> rawFile = sc.textFile(path);
        JavaPariRDD<String, String> pairRdd = rawFile.mapToPair((s) -> {
            // DELIMITER can be accessed normally 
            String[] fields = s.split(DELIMITER);
            // turns out header is empty when runs in yarn, 
            // but works fine in standalone mode
            return new Tuple2<>(fields[header.indexOf("ip")], s);
        });

        // other operations continue
    }

}
```

I understand that variables like `DELIMITER` and `header` are serialized to workers in cluster mode. But how can array `header` being empty inside rdd operation.

I modify the code by declare a final int variable `index` outside the `mapToPair` and access `index` inside then this error fixed.

But I'm still confused about the why `header` is empty when access inside `mapToPair`. Can anybody provides some insights?

Comment: The first "d" in "rdd" is *distributed*; there is a difference between an executor node and a data node. However, fret not; you can pass the header into your `spark` context and then access it from the data nodes. Or just `broadcast` it. Either one should work.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what do you mean by passing header into spark context?